# Show disk usage in Nautilus/Thunar

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, storage, thunar

Is there a way (or an extensions) to display disk usage/remaining disk space, in Linux file browsers (Nautilus/Thunar) like what happens in Windows when you open My Computer/PC. I know conky can do that, but what of mounted drives.

Comment: Dolphin (default file manager in Kubuntu) shows disk usage by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Gnome disks.  It lists all the drives it can find on the left-hand side (including USB drives), whether they are mounted or not.  If you click on one of them, it shows the details on the right:

- formatting, partitions
- space used/available
- if mounted, where
- etc.

[image: screenshot of GNOME disks]

Answer (score 3):

### Command line tools

- There are several command line tools for this purpose, for example **`df -h`** and **`lsblk -f`** that display disk usage/remaining disk space for mounted partitions.

  ```
    xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
    tmpfs           1.6G  1.8M  1.6G   1% /run
    /dev/sdb3       9.8G  1.6G  7.7G  17% /isodevice
    /dev/loop0      1.6G  1.6G     0 100% /cdrom
    /dev/loop1      1.5G  1.5G     0 100% /rofs
    /cow            7.8G   30M  7.8G   1% /
    tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
    tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    tmpfs           7.8G  8.0K  7.8G   1% /tmp
    tmpfs           1.6G   20K  1.6G   1% /run/user/999
    /dev/sda1       150G  130G   13G  92% /media/xubuntu/bionic

    xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ lsblk -f
    NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL                   UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
    loop0  iso9660  Xubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64 2020-04-23-07-50-17-00                     0   100% /cdrom
    loop1  squashfs                                                                    0   100% /rofs
    sda                                                                                         
    ├─sda1 ext4     bionic                  2093f8d6-7840-4256-8edc-4db97e865784   12.2G    87% /media/xubuntu/bionic
    ├─sda2 swap                             4b882c9f-4867-4c5c-8eb7-c84ef03f4786                [SWAP]
    └─sda3 ext4     focal                   31f64dfc-933a-4f48-9209-e7a7b016d8c9                
    sdb                                                                                         
    ├─sdb1                                                                                      
    ├─sdb2 vfat     usbboot                 02D3-7915                                           
    └─sdb3 ext4     isodevice               04d5aa8c-aa1e-4a71-9d79-edaf6e8b2111    7.7G    16% /isodevice
    sr0                                                                                         
    xubuntu@xubuntu:~$
  ```

### `baobab`

- You can also [install and] use **`baobab`**, which displays disk usage/remaining disk space for mounted partitions. `baobab` has a graphical desktop environment.

  [image]

  But the main purpose of `baobab` is to show the disk usage by directories and files with graphics. So when you click on one of the partition icons, you may see the following view,

  [image]

### `gparted`

- You can also [install and] use **`gparted`**, which displays disk usage/remaining disk space for mounted as well as unmounted partitions. `gparted` has a graphical desktop environment.

  - Use the small box near the top right corner of the window in order to select which drive to look at.
  - Mounted partitions are indicated with a key icon, showing that they are locked for editing (but you can unmount them).

  [image]

---

### Thunar

- **Thunar** has a 'status line' at the bottom of its window, where the free space in the displayed partition is displayed. But I have not found any display in Thunar, that displays the remaining space in all partitions at the same time.

Comment: I think I like `baobob` the most

Comment: There is also `gnome-usage` which is similar to `baobab`.

Answer (score 3):

In Nautilus you just right-click on the white space inside the folder (or any folder icon) and choose "Properties". The last record in the popup dialogue window is "Free space".

[image]

If you do this in the root folder of the disk, you also get information about used space, total capacity and filesystem type.

[image]